# How to compare data of two rows and put difference in other column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

```
       Diff  abc  
row1    3    xyz
row2    5    xyz
row3    10   xyz
row3    13   xyz
row3    15   xyz
```

And I want compare of two row's column like (row2.Diff - row1.Diff) into any other column.

```
Result
2    (r2.diff  - r1.diff)
5    (r3.diff  - r2.diff)
3    (r4.diff  - r3.diff)
2   (r5.diff  - r4.diff)
```

Comment: Guys please let me know if want more clarification. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should specify what particular SQL engine it is. SQL Server, MySQL, PostgresSQL or something other. It matters

Comment: Also, if sql server, which version (2008?, 2012?, 2016)

Comment: Use the `lag()` function. You also need a column to sort the rows, because rows in a relational database are ***NOT*** sorted.

Comment: Hey Sorry for did not mention sql version. It's 2008r2. Thanks Guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

answers specific to sql server

```
;with cte
as
(
select *,row_number() over (order by diff) as rownum
from #tmp
)
select 
c1.*,c2.diff-c1.diff as result
from cte c1
left join
cte c2 on c1.rownum+1=c2.rownum
```

if using SQLserver2012 or above..

```
select *,isnull(lead(diff) over (order by diff)-diff,0) as difff
from #tmp
```

Comment: `Left Join` should be changed to `Inner Join` since OP does not want the first row.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2008, I would `cross apply`.  The ordering of the rows is not 100% clear, but it seems based on `diff`:

```
select t.diff - t2.diff
from t cross apply
     (select top 1 t2.*
      from t t2
      where t2.diff < t.diff
      order by t2.diff desc
     ) t2;
```